# Values entered into input using google chrome console not registering unless I manually click the input and add and remove characters

Tags: javascript, angular, input, automation, console

I am trying to streamline downloading content from Youtube so I can listen to podcasts while not around internet. Here is what I have come up with so far.

```js
// I'd run this first to get to the page
this.document.location = 'https://youtubetoaudio.com/youtubetomp3';

// this should put the link in the search box and search.
async function fetchPromise() {
  const response = fetch('https://youtubetoaudio.com/youtubetomp3');
};

// the url I'm entering in the next piece of code isn't actually registering unless 
// I manually click in the box and add and delete a character.
fetchPromise().then((response) => {
  document.querySelector('#videoinput').value = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzeIbIFnzc4&list=WL&index=7';
});

// these next pieces won't work which should download the first link on the next page.
document.forms[0].searchbtn.click();
document.querySelector('#MP3').getElementsByTagName("button")[0].click();
```

I was expecting the file to download from the link I searched, but it appears as if setting the value with the below doesn't actually set the value and the search fails.

```
document.querySelector('#videoinput').value = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzeIbIFnzc4&list=WL&index=7';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https://youtubetoaudio.com/youtubetomp3` uses Angular under the hood. Angular updates the model on `input` event. You should trigger it manually, after you set the value.

```
const inputElement = document.querySelector('#videoinput');
inputElement.value = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzeIbIFnzc4&list=WL&index=7';
inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {
  view: window,
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true
}))
```

It is important to understand, that in different frameworks, the event type that propagates the changes under the hood may differ. ('change' event for instance)

Comment: I'm not really a programmer by trade so I don't really understand that bit of code you used but it did indeed fix my issue. I think what you are trying to say is that I was only updating my view of the page and the server didn't know about the value I updated. After firing the dispatchEvent the server understood that I had indeed updated the value of the inputElement. Would the only way for me to figure this out to be to learn more angular? A million thanks. I was bashing my head against the wall and knew I had about 90% there and just couldn't figure out the last 10%